# Simplifying problem in combinatorial designs

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Know the identities $r(k-1)=\lambda(v-1)$ and $bk=vr$ and obviously $v,k,\lambda,b,r\in \mathbb{N}_1$.

I came across this inequality when proving Fisher's inequality in a way that doesn't involve any matrices:
$$(1) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(b-1)k(r-1)+(b-1)k(k-1)(\lambda-1)\geq k^2(r-1)^2 $$
And supposedly we should be able to simplify the inequality to the form:
$$ (2) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(r − k)(r − \lambda)(v − k) \geq 0,$$
from which we could deduce that $r\geq k$ and hence $b\geq v$ which would prove Fisher's inequality. But how can we do the simplifying from (1) to (2). I tried to just naturally start dividing out stuff and tried to use the identities which are obviously needed here, but they only made things more complicated so maybe there are some tricks I am not seeing. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: A reference for those not acquainted to this subject : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_inequality